# Get column name from one table by id in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables 
Table 1:

```
Query_code | Item_code | Column_Name 
     2     |     1     |    CN1
     2     |     2     |    CN2
     2     |     3     |    CN3
```

Table 2:

```
Query_code | Source_item| dest_item | pair_code
     2     |     1      |    2      |    1
     2     |     2      |    3      |    2
```

What i want to achive is to get source_item-dest_item as result.
According to data that will be:

```
CN1-CN2
CN2-CN3
```

What i tried is:

```
   SELECT A.Column_Name 
FROM TABLE1 A  inner join 
TABLE2 B
ON A.QUERY_CODE=B.QUERY_CODE
```

But this is not even close to my goal

Comment: Join tableA twice. (One time for source, and one for dest.)

Comment: Your question is confusing, because your column name is "Column_Name".

Comment: @PeterAbolins CN1,CN2,CN3 are under column name

Comment: @jarlh i will try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It is unclear what your Query_Code is meant to do, so I omitted it from the query.

**EDIT** Inserted Query_code condition as well.

```
SELECT 
    Source.Column_Name || '-' || Dest.Column_Name AS ResultPair 
FROM 
    TABLE2 B 
        INNER JOIN TABLE1 Source 
            ON B.source_item = Source.item_code AND B.Query_code = Source.Query_code
        INNER JOIN TABLE1 Dest 
            ON B.dest_item = Dest.item_code AND B.Query_code = Dest.Query_code;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is use `TABLE2` to identify the `source_item` and `dest_item`, then join with `TABLE1` the first time to replace `source_item` with the column name, and join again with `TABLE1` to replace `dest_item` with the other column name.

```
SELECT A.Column_Name, B.Column_Name
  FROM t2 C 
  LEFT JOIN t1 A 
     ON C.Source_item=A.Item_code 
  LEFT JOIN t1 B 
     ON C.Dest_item=B.Item_code
  WHERE C.Query_code=A.Query_code 
     AND C.Query_code=B.Query_code
```

Running Example on **[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52d73a/6)**

Comment: I think also query_code should be added AND C.QUERY_CODE=A.QUERY_CODE

Comment: That depends on how you want to use `query_code` .. Do both source and destination items need to match the query code? what if only one of them match and the other doesn't? The condition depends on what type of behavior you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
WITH table1  (query_code, item_code ,column_name ) AS 
(SELECT 2,1,'cn1' UNION ALL 
 SELECT 2,2,'cn2' UNION ALL 
 SELECT 2,3,'cn3'),
table2  (query_code , source_item, dest_item , pair_code) AS 
(SELECT 2,1,2,1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 2,2,3,2)
SELECT a.column_name || '-' || c.column_name
FROM table1 a  
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.item_code=b.source_item
INNER JOIN table1 c ON c.item_code=b.dest_item;
```